# Getting the value of selected Spinner item in an alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-xml

I wanted to get the selected spinner item in an `AlertDialog`. But if I'm trying to print the value with `Snackbar` I'm getting a `NullPointerException`. How can I refer to the spinner value in the `AlertDialog`?

The Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference.
```

Dialog's code:

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    // Set title of the dialog
    builder.setTitle("ToDo hinzufügen");
    // Set view to dialog.xml
    builder.setView(R.layout.dialog);


    // To add ToDos for a specific section
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /*Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();*/

            // save entry in database and refresh the page
            builder.setPositiveButton("Hinzufügen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    alert.dismiss();


                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.fab), spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
```

dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:hint="Kategorie auswählen"
        android:entries="@array/tab_categeory"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Was möchten Sie erledigen?"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the comple exception message.

Comment: Further you are encouraged to google for NullPointerException. And tell us which pointer would be null.

Comment: Please show us the instantiation of the spinner

Comment: i added the instantiation

Comment: @y4cO did you solved it...?

Comment: no i did not solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this bro!**

```
    private String value;
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

            // Set title of the dialog
            builder.setTitle("ToDo hinzufügen");
            // Set view to dialog.xml
            builder.setView(R.layout.dialog);

            spinner .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                    value= adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString;

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                }
            });

 final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            // To add ToDos for a specific section
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    /*Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();*/

                    // save entry in database and refresh the page
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Hinzufügen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            alert.dismiss();


                            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.fab), value, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
                        }
                    });
```

**Let me know if this works, if not , Im here to keep trying until we get the solution! ;)**

**P.S** I updated my answer but I am not completely sure. Take a Look to the next example:

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()); //or context() if depends

View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_layout, null);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

// set dialog message

alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("My Dialog..");
alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
// create alert dialog
final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

final Spinner mSpinner= (Spinner) promptsView
        .findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
final Button mButton = (Button) promptsView
        .findViewById(R.id.myButton);

// reference UI elements from my_dialog_layout in similar fashion

mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnSpinnerItemClicked());

// show it
alertDialog.show();
```

**Also you can be missing alert.show , so when you clicked the Fab button it does not anything because you have never sent the AlertDialog.**

Comment: Not working, still the same exception as before. **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference**. Line: spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener

Comment: I think I know what is wrong with this!  We are missing to add our Spinner to our view, so that is why the view does not know the Spinner.

Comment: i changed `getApplicationContext()` to `this` and now everything works well

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {

            String selected_val=spinner_button.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected_val ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: still NullPointerException and not the answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the method `getApplicationContext()`. I changed it to `this` and now its working all good:

```
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your spinner object is null. It means `Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.Id.spinner)` is returning null object. Cross check the layout of the contentView.

Or try this:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null); // this line          
 builder.setView(v);
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinner)
```

Then set OnItemClickListener to the spinner object.